# C++ design of a multi-threaded sort? Futures vs Threadpool vs others?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting

I'm looking to parallelize bucket sort as an exercise. I am sorting integers lexiographically.

The motivation is, this is my first time doing any form of parallel programming. I'm trying to learn about the different ways of doing it, advantages/disadvantages.

E.g. {1,6,2,6778,8,2,43,52,23} -> [1 2 2 23 43 52 6 6778 8]

There are 3 steps to the task:

Initialize 9 vectors, 1 for each final bucket.

1) sort a chunk into buckets. This step parallelized by giving each thread a portion of the data.

2) sort each bucket into lexicographic order

3) concat all buckets

Visualization of the sort:

[image]

**Option 1: Threadpool**
I'm considering either dividing up all those tasks into jobs for 2 different functions, a bucketize function and a sort_bucket function then feeding them into a thread pool.

**Option 2: Futures**
Alternatively create futures of the functions and wait at the end of each step. Wait for all futures to return at the end of step 1, then create futures of sort_bucket in step 2 and join them.
Can anyone provide any opinions on these methods?

CPU utilization:
I can be sure that in the threadpool version I am using the appropirate number of threads as regards to available processors. In futures, they would be scheduled appropriately by the OS?

Are there other ways I've missed out on? I'm trying to learn so would like to compare all the possible methods of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is one way better than the other? Performance wise? style wise? Is there a third way I've missed thinking about. Thanks!

Comment: Conceptually you should use tasks over threads. That is why i would recommend going the futures way, but the implementation can use a threadpool.

Comment: @OutOfBound do you mean I could implement the futures way with a threadpool or the compiler's implementation? Thanks!

Comment: BTW, what motivates this particular exercise? You should edit your question to improve it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks, I've edited it to clarify my motivation.

Comment: Futures are a element of synchronisation rather than execution. If you get a future, you have a contract that you will at some point in time receive a value by a promise. How the promise is fufiled is up to you. You can use Pthreads, std::threads, std::async or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort subsequences of the initial array (in parallel, so in different threads) then merge them.

BTW the overhead is not negligible. You probably need to get an initial array of many dozen of thousands to observe a gain in parallelisation, and you are likely to sometimes observe some loss (e.g. with a too small initial array).

And for a first multi-threaded project, I'll rather suggest having a (nearly) fixed small set of threads (at most a dozen of them, assuming your computer has 8 cores). So both thread pools and futures are IMHO too complex for that.

Threads are heavy and expensive. They need at least a call stack (of a megabyte) each, and actually much more.

Don't forget synchronization (e.g. with mutexes).

This is a [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) that you could adapt to C++ threads.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep in mind the overhead. In production maybe I'd have a switch that uses the parallel version only if the number or elements to be sorted is above a threshold?

Comment: @killingtime1: A common pattern seen in sorting is that you switch strategies depending on the remaining size to sort. It's not unusual to switch to a hand-coded non-recursive sort for <8 elements. You can do the same for <10.000 elements

Comment: A simple approach I used on a 4 core processor was to split the array into 4 parts, spawn 3 threads for 2nd thru 4th parts, and use the current thread for the 1st part. The code simply waited for threads to complete instead of mutexes to know when to start merging. 3rd thread waited for 4th thread to complete, then merged 3rd and 4th parts. 1st thread waited for 2nd thread, merged 1st and 2nd parts, waited for 3rd thread to complete, then merged 1st and 2nd halves.